# interrupt handler not executing.....in am335x BBB

Tags: interrupt, interrupt-handling, u-boot, interrupted-exception

I am working on ti-am335x BBB and trying to make an interrupt work at u-boot spl level(no os level).I read the flow of u-boot code from the following link... http://www.programering.com/a/MzMwcTNwATI.html 
the thing i did is i defined "CONFIG_USE_IRQ" in the config files and removed all the dependencies errors like defining "arch_interrupt_init()". now here is the snapshot of start.S file...

"**

```
#ifdef CONFIG_USE_IRQ
    .align  5
irq:
    get_irq_stack
    irq_save_user_regs
    bl  do_irq
    irq_restore_user_regs
```

** "

now A/C to my understanding in case of irq pre-emption to the cpu core which is done by "enable_interrupt()" in the file arch/arm/lib/interrupt.c and interrupt arrival,
the above mentioned code should execute....
but, the problem is as soon as the interrupt is arriving the system is hanging.....,I am quite desperately looking for the reason this is happening..Any help,leads,links would be truley appreciated.

thanks in Advance,
sumit

Comment: If you want to show code, please edit your question, highlight the block of code and hit the `{}` button to get better formatting. I'd do it for you but not being familiar with what you're doing, I don't know whether the `"` characters are meant to be part of what you're showing.

Comment: thanks Damien_The_Unbeliever